# How to SELECT certain rows based on comparison of 2 columns in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table as follows:

```
id male female m_age f_age
1  bob  jane   27    25
2  sam  sue    29    31
3  fred barb   22    22
4  dave joan   30    28
```

I want to only return the name of the person who is older. Result:

```
bob
sue
dave
```

My might the mysql query look like to do this?

here is what I have so far.

```
$result = mysql_query('
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN m_age > f_age then male
            WHEN m_age < f_age then female
        END
        AS person
    FROM people
') or die(mysql_error());
```

But my query is returning a blank row on the fred equaling barb and I do not want that row returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include a `WHERE` clause to exclude the rows when the ages are the same:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN m_age > f_age then male
    WHEN m_age < f_age then female
  END AS person
FROM people
where m_age <> f_age
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/980d9/4)

Or you can include an `ELSE` with a value to return if the age's match:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN m_age > f_age then male
    WHEN m_age < f_age then female
    ELSE 'Ages match'
  END AS person
FROM people;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/980d9/6)

Comment: Ah, clever...thanks @bluefeet. My mind was focused inside the CASE and I didn't even think outside the box :)

Comment: @H.Ferrence The `null` is coming from the `else` part of the `CASE`, since you exclude it you get `null`.  :)

Comment: I added this into my script and it worked perfectly. i'll accept this as the answer when SO allows me too